# How to get JAXB (xjc) to stop adding underscores between characters and numbers

Tags: jaxb, xjc

In my code I need to map enumerated types from an XML file based on my schema to an enumerated type in another part of the code and vice versa.

The problem is that a construct like:

```
<simpleType name="sensorKindType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2" />
        <enumeration value="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3" />
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Will cause the following to be generated.

```
@XmlEnumValue("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2")
ATS_S_2_VOLTAGE_1_2("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2"),
@XmlEnumValue("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3")
ATS_S_2_VOLTAGE_2_3("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3"),
```

However, what I would prefer is to have the following:

```
@XmlEnumValue("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2")
ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2"),
@XmlEnumValue("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3")
ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3("ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3"),
```

In other words, no underscore between the S and the 2.

Comment: Did this issue got resolved? I am facing the same problem, can you please help?

Comment: No, I never did get a resolution. I was able to get around it somewhat by using the .value() method but that didn't solve my problem entirely. I did get a badge from StackOverflow for having an unanswered question for a long time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the names of the generated enums using a custom JAXB binding. If you have access to the schema, then you can inline these bindings in the schema as shown below. If you don't have access to the schema then you can define these preferences in an external bindings file.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
       targetNamespace="stackoverflow"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       jaxb:version="2.1"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">

<xs:simpleType name="sensorKindType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3"/>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This worked fine for me with the default settings for the JAXB maven plugin with the snippet below in your pom file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The following type is generated:

```
@XmlType(name = "sensorKindType", namespace = "stackoverflow")
@XmlEnum
public enum SensorKindType {

    ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_1_2,
    ATS_S2_VOLTAGE_2_3;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static SensorKindType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```